# Finding very high multiple peak element leaving the rest low peaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis, peak-detection

I have a bunch of values stored in an array, I need to find the very highest peak. I tried using this code:

```
arr=["values"]
n=len(arr)
if arr == []:
print (pos)
Diff = []
for i in range(0,n-1):
    if arr[i]< arr[i+1]:
       Diff.append(1)
    elif arr[i] == arr[i+1]:
       Diff.append(0)
    if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
       Diff.append(-1)
pos = []
peaks = []
j = 0
for i in range(0,n-2):
   if Diff[i] == 1 and Diff[i+1] == -1:
     pos.append(i+1)
     peaks.append(arr[i+1])
   if Diff[i] == 1 and Diff[i+1] == 0:
     if Diff[i+1:] == [Diff[i+1]]:
        break
     j = i+1
     while(Diff[j] == 0 and j < n-2):
        j = j+1
     if Diff[j] == -1:
        pos.append(i+1)
        peaks.append(arr[i+1])
print (pos)
print (peaks)
```

But what I get is all the peaks, I am trying to solve to get the highest peak alone.

The data i have is:

```
A=['5662', '5660', '5658', '5658', '5658', '5658', '5655', '5653', '5655', '5660', '5664', '5664', '5662', '5655', '5655', '5655', '5658', '5664', '5674', '5685', '5694', '5699', '5701', '5704', '5706', '5708', '5704', '5701', '5704', '5708', '5713', '5720', '5720', '5724', '5733', '5745', '5761', '5777', '5798', '5819', '5832', '5842', '5846', '5851', '5858', '5862', '5865', '5869', '5874', '5874', '5867', '5855', '5851', '5855', '5865', '5874', '5878', '5883', '5888', '5892', '5897', '5899', '5901', '5901', '5904', '5899', '5894', '5890', '5894', '5899', '5904', '5904', '5894', '5881', '5860', '5839', '5823', '5814', '5809', '5805', '5798', '5791', '5786', '5782', '5779', '5777', '5775', '5773', '5775', '5777', '5779', '5779', '5773', '5763', '5752', '5745', '5740', '5738', '5729', '5717', '5701', '5687', '5678', '5674', '5664', '5653', '5646', '5646', '5651', '5655', '5655', '5653', '5651', '5646', '5646', '5646', '5648', '5653', '5653', '5653', '5653', '5655', '5662', '5664', '5660', '5651', '5648', '5651', '5658', '5662', '5662', '5660', '5658', '5653', '5648', '5648', '5653', '5658', '5658', '5658', '5658', '5662', '5667', '5664', '5658', '5651', '5653', '5655', '5658', '5660', '5662', '5664', '5664', '5660', '5655', '5658', '5664', '5667', '5667', '5664', '5667', '5669', '5669', '5664', '5660', '5658', '5660', '5662', '5664', '5669', '5674', '5674', '5669', '5664', '5662', '5660', '5660', '5658', '5658', '5662', '5669', '5671', '5669', '5662', '5660', '5660', '5664', '5664', '5667', '5667', '5667', '5664', '5660', '5660', '5662', '5664', '5664', '5664', '5667', '5671', '5676', '5674', '5669', '5667', '5664', '5662', '5660', '5662', '5667', '5671', '5674', '5671', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5669', '5667', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5667', '5671', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5678', '5674', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5694', '5701', '5706', '5706', '5708', '5713', '5720', '5727', '5729', '5733', '5731', '5724', '5717', '5715', '5717', '5724', '5727', '5727', '5727', '5727', '5727', '5724', '5720', '5713', '5713', '5715', '5715', '5713', '5708', '5701', '5694', '5687', '5681', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5676', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5687', '5687', '5683', '5678', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5690', '5708', '5736', '5766', '5798', '5830', '5871', '5924', '5984', '6044', '6106', '6175', '6262', '6359', '6456', '6543', '6614', '6667', '6688', '6663', '6589', '6488', '6382', '6281', '6175', '6060', '5943', '5839', '5763', '5708', '5660', '5623', '5602', '5602', '5609', '5612', '5612', '5612', '5616', '5625', '5635', '5641', '5648', '5655', '5660', '5664', '5664', '5662', '5662', '5664', '5664', '5667', '5664', '5662', '5662', '5667', '5671', '5676', '5671', '5662', '5658', '5662', '5671', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5671', '5671', '5664', '5660', '5660', '5667', '5674', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5685', '5692', '5697', '5701', '5704', '5708', '5715', '5717', '5715', '5715', '5715', '5713', '5710', '5710', '5717', '5733', '5750', '5761', '5773', '5786', '5805', '5823', '5837', '5846', '5853', '5865', '5876', '5883', '5885', '5885', '5883', '5876', '5869', '5865', '5862', '5871', '5881', '5888', '5894', '5897', '5899', '5901', '5901', '5904', '5906', '5908', '5911', '5911', '5908', '5908', '5908', '5904', '5899', '5897', '5897', '5897', '5888', '5869', '5846', '5828', '5816', '5812', '5805', '5798', '5793', '5796', '5796', '5796', '5796', '5793', '5789', '5786', '5782', '5779', '5779', '5775', '5768', '5759', '5754', '5747', '5738', '5720', '5699', '5685', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5671', '5667', '5664', '5660', '5658', '5660', '5667', '5671', '5671', '5669', '5669', '5669', '5667', '5664', '5658', '5658', '5662', '5664', '5664', '5664', '5664', '5664', '5662', '5658', '5658', '5660', '5667', '5669', '5667', '5662', '5662', '5664', '5669', '5667', '5660', '5658', '5660', '5667', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5664', '5658', '5658', '5664', '5671', '5674', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5667', '5664', '5664', '5662', '5662', '5667', '5669', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5667', '5671', '5678', '5681', '5676', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5676', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5676', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5685', '5685', '5681', '5674', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5676', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5676', '5681', '5685', '5687', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5690', '5683', '5674', '5674', '5683', '5694', '5704', '5710', '5715', '5722', '5727', '5729', '5729', '5727', '5727', '5727', '5727', '5729', '5733', '5736', '5736', '5731', '5727', '5727', '5729', '5733', '5731', '5729', '5729', '5733', '5736', '5733', '5724', '5713', '5706', '5701', '5699', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5685', '5678', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5678', '5687', '5692', '5694', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5687', '5683', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5692', '5706', '5722', '5745', '5768', '5798', '5828', '5867', '5917', '5977', '6042', '6108', '6187', '6276', '6377', '6469', '6548', '6607', '6658', '6688', '6679', '6617', '6513', '6396', '6285', '6173', '6058', '5940', '5842', '5768', '5717', '5678', '5646', '5621', '5612', '5607', '5605', '5605', '5609', '5623', '5637', '5646', '5653', '5658', '5664', '5667', '5667', '5664', '5660', '5662', '5664', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5664', '5667', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5667', '5676', '5683', '5685', '5676', '5669', '5671', '5681', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5692', '5708', '5720', '5722', '5717', '5713', '5717', '5722', '5724', '5724', '5727', '5731', '5731', '5729', '5731', '5743', '5759', '5779', '5791', '5805', '5823', '5844', '5860', '5867', '5862', '5860', '5865', '5876', '5890', '5894', '5892', '5883', '5876', '5874', '5876', '5883', '5892', '5899', '5906', '5908', '5911', '5913', '5915', '5917', '5915', '5908', '5904', '5908', '5917', '5924', '5924', '5915', '5911', '5906', '5901', '5885', '5862', '5839', '5825', '5816', '5812', '5807', '5805', '5802', '5798', '5793', '5791', '5793', '5798', '5800', '5798', '5793', '5791', '5786', '5777', '5768', '5761', '5759', '5754', '5743', '5729', '5717', '5708', '5697', '5681', '5669', '5667', '5671', '5674', '5671', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5662', '5664', '5667', '5667', '5664', '5667', '5674', '5678', '5674', '5664', '5660', '5660', '5664', '5667', '5667', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5664', '5667', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5676', '5671', '5664', '5667', '5674', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5671', '5678', '5683', '5678', '5667', '5662', '5669', '5678', '5681', '5676', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5674', '5667', '5664', '5669', '5678', '5681', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5669', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5681', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5683', '5690', '5692', '5687', '5678', '5669', '5722', '5729', '5733', '5738', '5740', '5738', '5736', '5733', '5736', '5738', '5745', '5747', '5747', '5745', '5740', '5738', '5733', '5733', '5736', '5743', '5750', '5752', '5745', '5736', '5724', '5717', '5713', '5706', '5699', '5694', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5697', '5692', '5687', '5683', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5690', '5694', '5697', '5699', '5701', '5701', '5697', '5692', '5685', '5683', '5690', '5694', '5699', '5699', '5699', '5701', '5699', '5692', '5683', '5678', '5685', '5701', '5722', '5745', '5773', '5802', '5832', '5867', '5913', '5968', '6035', '6104', '6177', '6262', '6359', '6458', '6543', '6610', '6658', '6686', '6679', '6624', '6529', '6419', '6313', '6205', '6090', '5968', '5860', '5779', '5727', '5687', '5653', '5625', '5614', '5618', '5623', '5621', '5616', '5618', '5632', '5651', '5662', '5669', '5671', '5671', '5671', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5676', '5669', '5669', '5674', '5681', '5687', '5690', '5685', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5701', '5713', '5724', '5729', '5729', '5729', '5727', '5729', '5729', '5729', '5729', '5731', '5733', '5740', '5752', '5761', '5768', '5773', '5784', '5802', '5828', '5848', '5862', '5867', '5871', '5876', '5883', '5888', '5888', '5888', '5885', '5883', '5881', '5878', '5881', '5885', '5894', '5901', '5906', '5911', '5911', '5915', '5917', '5922', '5922', '5920', '5915', '5911', '5911', '5913', '5915', '5920', '5920', '5920', '5911', '5892', '5869', '5848', '5835', '5828', '5823', '5819', '5812', '5807', '5805', '5802', '5802', '5800', '5796', '5791', '5791', '5796', '5800', '5800', '5789', '5773', '5763', '5761', '5763', '5759', '5743', '5724', '5706', '5699', '5697', '5692', '5685', '5676', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5681', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5674', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5671', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5667', '5667', '5671', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5671', '5667', '5669', '5671', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5685', '5683', '5676', '5669', '5669', '5678', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5683', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5687', '5690', '5685', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5683', '5687', '5687', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5681', '5687', '5690', '5685', '5676', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5678', '5683', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5687', '5681', '5681', '5685', '5690', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5685', '5681', '5678', '5681', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5685', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5685', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5694', '5692', '5687', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5694', '5706', '5715', '5720', '5717', '5715', '5717', '5722', '5729', '5733', '5733', '5733', '5738', '5740', '5738', '5733', '5731', '5733', '5736', '5738', '5740', '5743', '5747', '5747', '5743', '5736', '5733', '5738', '5738', '5729', '5717', '5708', '5708', '5713', '5706', '5694', '5685', '5683', '5690', '5697', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5692', '5697', '5701', '5697', '5692', '5690', '5692', '5697', '5697', '5694', '5694', '5697', '5699', '5699', '5699', '5706', '5722', '5740', '5761', '5786', '5819', '5860', '5911', '5966', '6026', '6088', '6157', '6237', '6331', '6428', '6520', '6596', '6653', '6690', '6688', '6640', '6550', '6440', '6329', '6226', '6118', '6005', '5894', '5805', '5743', '5697', '5658', '5625', '5609', '5607', '5609', '5614', '5621', '5632', '5641', '5646', '5646', '5651', '5662', '5676', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5678', '5683', '5681', '5676', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5674', '5671', '5676', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5694', '5701', '5704', '5704', '5708', '5717', '5727', '5729', '5727', '5724', '5729', '5736', '5736', '5729', '5722', '5724', '5736', '5752', '5768', '5784', '5800', '5814', '5828', '5842', '5858', '5869', '5874', '5874', '5874', '5883', '5899', '5908', '5899', '5881', '5865', '5865', '5874', '5888', '5899', '5906', '5908', '5911', '5908', '5906', '5911', '5917', '5922', '5922', '5917', '5917', '5920', '5924', '5922', '5915', '5908', '5906', '5904', '5899', '5885', '5865', '5844', '5830', '5821', '5816', '5807', '5800', '5798', '5802', '5807', '5807', '5802', '5800', '5800', '5800', '5796', '5789', '5779', '5777', '5775', '5773', '5763', '5750', '5738', '5724', '5708', '5694', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5683', '5687', '5683', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5674', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5676', '5667', '5660', '5664', '5674', '5683', '5685', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5683', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5683', '5678', '5678', '5685', '5690', '5692', '5687', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5687', '5690', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5694', '5697', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5690', '5694', '5697', '5697', '5694', '5687', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5692', '5701', '5715', '5722', '5727', '5729', '5731', '5733', '5736', '5731', '5729', '5729', '5731', '5738', '5743', '5740', '5738', '5736', '5738', '5740', '5745', '5745', '5743', '5740', '5743', '5747', '5745', '5736', '5722', '5710', '5704', '5701', '5701', '5701', '5701', '5699', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5697', '5697', '5699', '5699', '5697', '5692', '5687', '5685', '5687', '5692', '5694', '5699', '5701', '5704', '5699', '5694', '5690', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5701', '5704', '5708', '5706', '5699', '5687', '5678', '5676', '5685', '5701', '5720', '5738', '5759', '5786', '5816', '5851', '5890', '5943', '6003', '6069', '6138', '6219', '6308', '6410', '6502', '6575', '6630', '6674', '6690', '6665', '6589', '6479', '6359', '6249', '6138', '6026', '5915', '5819', '5745', '5692', '5653', '5628', '5618', '5621', '5621', '5614', '5607', '5609', '5628', '5651', '5664', '5667', '5664', '5662', '5667', '5671', '5674', '5669', '5667', '5664', '5671', '5683', '5690', '5687', '5678', '5669', '5664', '5667', '5671', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5683', '5692', '5704', '5710', '5717', '5720', '5724', '5729', '5727', '5722', '5717', '5720', '5724', '5733', '5738', '5740', '5740', '5743', '5752', '5763', '5779', '5800', '5821', '5842', '5853', '5862', '5867', '5871', '5878', '5883', '5888', '5885', '5885', '5885', '5883', '5883', '5881', '5881', '5885', '5897', '5906', '5911', '5911', '5911', '5915', '5922', '5922', '5915', '5911', '5906', '5911', '5913', '5915', '5915', '5917', '5917', '5908', '5894', '5874', '5855', '5844', '5835', '5823', '5816', '5814', '5814', '5809', '5805', '5796', '5793', '5796', '5800', '5802', '5800', '5800', '5798', '5791', '5782', '5770', '5763', '5759', '5752', '5745', '5731', '5720', '5708', '5694', '5683', '5671', '5671', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5667', '5669', '5674', '5674', '5669', '5667', '5669', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5681', '5685', '5681', '5671', '5664', '5667', '5674', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5676', '5667', '5664', '5671', '5683', '5687', '5683', '5674', '5671', '5678', '5683', '5683', '5671', '5662', '5662', '5669', '5681', '5687', '5685', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5685', '5687', '5683', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5685', '5687', '5683', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5678', '5685', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5685', '5678', '5676', '5681', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5690', '5694', '5692', '5687', '5681', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5690', '5697', '5697', '5687', '5681', '5678', '5685', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5697', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5687', '5690', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5692', '5694', '5701', '5701', '5692', '5681', '5676', '5681', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5701', '5710', '5717', '5720', '5720', '5724', '5731', '5736', '5738', '5740', '5743', '5745', '5740', '5733', '5729', '5733', '5743', '5745', '5743', '5738', '5738', '5743', '5743', '5738', '5731', '5729', '5731', '5733', '5731', '5727', '5720', '5710', '5701', '5692', '5687', '5690', '5697', '5701', '5699', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5690', '5692', '5699', '5701', '5701', '5697', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5690', '5683', '5685', '5692', '5701', '5699', '5694', '5692', '5694', '5699', '5699', '5694', '5694', '5699', '5710', '5727', '5750', '5777', '5809', '5846', '5890', '5940', '5998', '6055', '6118', '6191', '6283', '6384', '6483', '6564', '6626', '6670', '6686', '6663', '6594', '6490', '6380', '6279', '6175', '6062', '5945', '5846', '5770', '5717', '5671', '5635', '5614', '5614', '5623', '5625', '5621', '5618', '5625', '5639', '5651', '5658', '5660', '5664', '5671', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5667', '5667', '5671', '5681', '5685', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5681', '5685', '5687', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5678', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5692', '5701', '5708', '5713', '5715', '5720', '5727', '5733', '5733', '5731', '5727', '5724', '5727', '5729', '5733', '5740', '5747', '5759', '5773', '5784', '5798', '5814', '5830', '5844', '5853', '5858', '5865', '5876', '5890', '5901', '5899', '5888', '5876', '5869', '5869', '5874', '5881', '5888', '5897', '5904', '5906', '5908', '5908', '5911', '5913', '5917', '5917', '5920', '5922', '5924', '5922', '5915', '5911', '5911', '5915', '5915', '5904', '5885', '5867', '5853', '5839', '5828', '5814', '5807', '5805', '5807', '5809', '5807', '5807', '5809', '5807', '5798', '5789', '5786', '5791', '5791', '5786', '5775', '5766', '5761', '5761', '5750', '5733', '5715', '5704', '5697', '5694', '5687', '5683', '5676', '5671', '5667', '5664', '5664', '5667', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5669', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5676', '5669', '5662', '5662', '5669', '5678', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5685', '5690', '5685', '5676', '5669', '5669', '5676', '5681', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5683', '5678', '5676', '5685', '5694', '5697', '5690', '5683', '5681', '5687', '5692', '5685', '5678', '5676', '5678', '5687', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5683', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5683', '5681', '5683', '5690', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5699', '5699', '5697', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5694', '5690', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5697', '5697', '5694', '5687', '5681', '5681', '5685', '5692', '5701', '5706', '5713', '5722', '5733', '5738', '5740', '5738', '5733', '5733', '5736', '5740', '5743', '5745', '5740', '5738', '5736', '5733', '5736', '5740', '5740', '5740', '5738', '5738', '5743', '5745', '5743', '5733', '5720', '5713', '5710', '5708', '5704', '5697', '5692', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5699', '5701', '5699', '5694', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5694', '5699', '5701', '5701', '5699', '5692', '5687', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5692', '5701', '5706', '5704', '5692', '5683', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5690', '5694', '5706', '5727', '5752', '5777', '5800', '5830', '5869', '5920', '5980', '6046', '6115', '6191', '6274', '6366', '6458', '6543', '6614', '6667', '6695', '6683', '6621', '6525', '6414', '6306', '6200', '6085', '5963', '5855', '5775', '5727', '5687', '5651', '5623', '5614', '5616', '5618', '5616', '5616', '5628', '5646', '5662', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5669', '5669', '5674', '5681', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5671', '5671', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5681', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5683', '5674', '5669', '5671', '5678', '5685', '5685', '5683', '5678', '5681', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5687', '5694', '5704', '5713', '5722', '5727', '5727', '5722', '5722', '5722', '5727', '5731', '5733', '5736', '5736', '5736', '5738', '5747', '5759', '5775', '5796', '5814', '5830', '5846', '5858', '5865', '5867', '5867', '5871', '5883', '5894', '5899', '5892', '5881', '5874', '5874', '5885', '5892', '5899', '5904', '5908', '5913', '5917', '5922', '5927', '5924', '5920', '5913', '5911', '5913', '5922', '5927', '5924', '5920', '5917', '5913', '5901', '5885', '5867', '5853', '5842', '5832', '5825', '5819', '5812', '5802', '5798', '5798', '5798', '5800', '5798', '5793', '5793', '5798', '5802', '5798', '5782', '5768', '5761', '5763', '5763', '5756', '5743', '5727', '5715', '5704', '5692', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5669', '5669', '5671', '5669', '5664', '5662', '5667', '5671', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5676', '5671', '5669', '5667', '5671', '5678', '5683', '5681', '5678', '5678', '5676', '5674', '5671', '5669', '5671', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5674', '5671', '5674', '5678', '5681', '5678', '5674', '5676', '5681', '5687', '5687', '5678', '5671', '5669', '5674', '5674', '5676', '5678', '5683', '5683', '5676', '5667', '5667', '5674', '5683', '5685', '5678', '5676', '5678', '5683', '5683', '5676', '5671', '5671', '5676', '5683', '5687', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5681', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5678', '5678', '5681', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5683', '5678', '5674', '5676', '5683', '5687', '5692', '5692', '5690', '5687', '5683', '5681', '5681', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5687', '5687', '5683', '5676', '5676', '5678', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5687', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5690', '5690', '5690', '5692', '5694', '5694', '5694', '5690', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5690', '5692', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5683', '5683', '5685', '5685', '5685', '5687', '5692', '5694', '5697', '5699', '5697', '5692', '5687', '5687', '5692', '5697', '5699', '5697', '5692', '5692', '5697', '5697', '5692', '5685', '5683', '5690', '5699', '5706', '5704', '5697', '5690', '5685', '5683', '5685', '5690', '5694', '5694', '5692', '5692', '5697', '5706', '5710', , '5860', '5862', '5865', '5869', '5878', '5888', '5892', '5892', '5890', '5883', '5878', '5874', '5876', '5883', '5890', '5899']
```

Kindly help.

Comment: What is peak here? Maximum value?

Comment: @sophros- yes, these values in array have an irregular variation. I need to find out the maximum values in that range . For this data values are from 5000-8000. I need the maximum values at most .

Comment: So what is the expected result for the example array you provided?

Comment: So, basically, it's just the max, is that right!? Because the range of values you've mentioned it's already in the top of the distribution.

Comment: @sophros- the expected values are from 6900-8000, these max value occur more than 2-3 times

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva- Yes, but to be precise i need the highest of em all. from that range . these value occur more than 1 time in that array.

Comment: @GotCraziness, ah, ok, got you now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your list of strings to a *numpy array* or *pandas Series*:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(A).astype(int)
```

Secondly, identify all extreme values (e.g. those in the extreme 1% of the distribution), then finally get the maximum value by consecutive values (peaks). We can easily identify the consecutive groups with [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

```py
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

grp_peaks = consecutive_groups(s[s >= s.quantile(.99)].index)
max_peaks = [s[grp].idxmax() for grp in grp_peaks]
print(s[max_peaks])
```

Output:

```
372     6688
787     6688
1132    6686
1547    6690
1963    6690
2378    6686
2793    6695
dtype: int64
```

**Data visualization:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(s, marker='o')

# Set a line delimiting the extreme 1% values of the distribution
plt.axhline(y=s.quantile(.99), color='r', linestyle='--')

# Identify the maximum value per peak
plt.plot(s[max_peaks], color='r', marker='o', linestyle='None')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

An approach to reproduce the results above without importing any libraries:

```py
# Convert list of strings to integers and get respective indexes
A = list(map(int, A))
idx = range(len(A))

# Calculate empirical p-values to get the peaks
pval = [1 - sum([i >= j for j in A]) / (len(A)+1) for i in A]

# Identify extreme values (peaks)
stat_pval = [idx for idx,p in enumerate(pval) if p <= 0.01]

# Identify consecutive indexes in target
grps = []
consec_idx = []
stat_pval.append(stat_pval[-1]+2)

for i in range(len(stat_pval)-1):
    if stat_pval[i] == stat_pval[i+1]-1:
        consec_idx.append(stat_pval[i])
    else:
        consec_idx.append(stat_pval[i])
        grps.append(consec_idx)
        consec_idx = []

del consec_idx
del stat_pval[-1]

# Then, identify the maximum value per peak:
[max(A[grp[0]:grp[-1]+1]) for grp in grps]
```

```
[6688, 6688, 6686, 6690, 6690, 6686, 6695]
```

Alternatively, if you wanna print both maximum values per peak, as well as their index:

```py
idx_and_max_per_peak = []
for grp in grps:
    peak = A[grp[0]:grp[-1]+1]
    peak_max = max(peak)
    idx_and_max_per_peak.extend([(grp[i], value) for i,value in enumerate(peak) if value==peak_max])
```

Output of `idx_and_max_per_peak`:

```
[(372, 6688),
 (787, 6688),
 (1132, 6686),
 (1547, 6690),
 (1963, 6690),
 (2378, 6686),
 (2793, 6695)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Is there any other way to get out the max values without using libraries.

Comment: Yeah, but it would require more code, and probably it would be less efficient as well. Don't you want to use any? Anyways, I'm leaving here for now. But later I can come with an approach using only built-in functions...

Comment: @GotCraziness, there're several ways to reproduce this code without importing any libraries (although, I strongly recommend using numpy). I've edited the answer with a possible approach. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, i tried the code without library. it just prints the whole array elements and at last prints syntax error. i dunno where did i made mistake

Comment: It's working fine to me (using your data). Maybe you'll need take a step-by-step approach to identify the error.

Comment: sure i will try

Comment: Yeah, I got it. While working on Jupyter Notebooks I get the output. But while compiling on system environment i.e on Command prompt it is not getting compiled.

Comment: Oh yeah! In this case you'll need `print` the results!

Comment: Actually, it is a set of ECG data. i am working on detecting the peaks, PQRST.

Comment: Right now I have identified the R peak. Thanks to you

Comment: Glad to help! Best wishes!

Comment: how to identify the lows ?? in this

Comment: like lows nearby, before and after highest,

Comment: You mean, to identify all values above the red dashed line? If so, you already have such information in the `stat_pval` variable (or using `s[s >= s.quantile(.99)]` from the first approach).

Comment: #the low peaks, Like the highest peak I need to find the lowest peak before and after the highest peak(R-peak).